# Why does getting from a closed multiprocessing.Queue not raise any errors?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multiprocessing

I was trying to do some multiprocessing.

```
import multiprocessing

def func(foo,q):
  for i in foo:
    do something
    q.put(something)
  q.close()

q=multiprocessing.Queue()
p=multiprocessing.Process(target=func,args=(foo,q))
p.start()
while True:
  try:
    q.get()
  except ValueError:
    break
```

This code then goes into an infinite loop.

I know that there are work arounds, in fact I have already implemented one. I just want to know why the queue doesn't raise `ValueError` like its supposed to, according to the docs.

Just to clarify, my understanding is that the queue will raise the error as long as it is closed and you call .get on it.

I’ve seen people suggesting setting timeout to 1 and breaking when the queue is empty but:

```
def func(q):
  for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(10)
    q.put(i)
```

Will cause the code to exit prematurely if we break when queue is empty

Answer (score 0):

> If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds and raises the Queue.Empty exception if no item was available within that time.

`while True` is an infinite loop if you are just giving `queue.Empty` a pass.

```
import multiprocessing
import queue

def func(a,b):
    print('func acquired {}\t{}'.format(a,b))

q = multiprocessing.Queue()
p=multiprocessing.Process(target=func,args=(range(5),q))
p.start()
while True:
  try:
    q.get(timeout=1)
  except queue.Empty:
    print("Empty")
    break
  except ValueError:
    break
print('termination')
```

Output:

```
func acquired range(0, 5)       <multiprocessing.queues.Queue object at 0x7f42d0989710>
Empty
termination
```

Comment: Okay I tried something else and made timeout None, it still didn’t work

Comment: If it still didn't work the issue is with your `func`, adding POC.

Comment: I made some changes to my original question

Answer (score 0):

first all of you are using `queue` as variable name so exception will handle `queue.Empty` second use `break` for while loop to stop

```
q = multiprocessing.Queue()
p=multiprocessing.Process(target=func,args=(range(5),q))
p.start()
while True:
  try:
    q.get(timeout=1)
  except queue.Empty:
    print("Empty")
    break
  except ValueError:
    break
```

**as docs say if you provide `block` true and `timeout` none this operation goes into an uninterruptible wait on an underlying lock.** [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get)

Comment: I change the variable name and excludes the timeout entirely. It still doesn’t raise anything.

Comment: set `timeout`  you will exception.

Comment: I don’t think this will work because the process is being executed asynchronously so maybe the queue is empty but the process is still running and trying to fill the queue.

Comment: Also I am not sure if the queue.Queue() and multiprocessing.Queue() have the same implementation even though they have the same api.

Comment: code is working fine for me i am getting exception according to `timeout` wait .  and according to docs they are near clone of queue.Queue

Comment: if u make func: def func: for i in range(10): time.sleep(10); queue.put(i). The code will exit prematurely.

Comment: @YEpd          can you explain more

Comment: func will be submitted to the process to run. Because func takes 10 seconds to run, the code will continue executing. When it reaches the q.get part it will wait one second, afterwards it will  raise Empty error and break. However, func is still running and trying to put things into the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Closing a queue only flushes the objects put in the queue to the thread calling `close()`. Other threads are not affected, things can still be put into the queue even if it is closed on the current thread.